# How to set height for the second div

Tags: html, css

i want to create 3 elements in three divs...

```
<body>
    <div id="first" style="height:100px"></div> <!-- a bar with 100px -->
    <div style="height:100% - 100px"> <!-- (not working)-->
        <div id="second" style="height:50%"></div> <!-- not working-->
        <div id="third" style="height:50%"></div> <!-- not working-->
    </div> 
    <style>
        html, body{
            height: 100%; 
            margin:0 !important;
            padding:0 !important;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

However, it's not work.
how can i do it?

Comment: Please explain how output should look... Your question is unclear. What is 100% - 100px ? Your div without id should have... 100% (from what?) - 100 px, or...?

Comment: maybe you should use calc function. `height:calc(100% - 100px);` but then again. What exactly do you want :D

Comment: Ok I think I get it, but there are more sophisticated ways of solving your problem. (instead of calc function you could use element positioning in your favor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first div is 100px height. The next div is 400px height. The second div is 50% of 400px height (200px) and the third div also 200px (50% of 400px).

```html
<div id="first" style="height: 100px;background:red;width:100%"></div>
<div style="height: calc(500px - 100px);width:100%">
    <div id="second" style="height:50%;float:left;background:yellow;width:100%"></div>
    <div id="third" style="height: 50%;float:left;background:blue;width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div style="height: calc(100% - 100px);width:100%"> it's work

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for relative widths, then do it like :

**html**

```
<body>
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- not working-->
    <div id="second">
      <p>
        Some Stuff here
        <br> Agains some stuff here.
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- not working-->

    <div id="third">
      <p>
        Some Stuff here.
        <br> A whole lot of useful stuff here!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

div#wrapper {
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
  height: -o-calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: green;
}

#wrapper #second,
#wrapper #third {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#wrapper * {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfo4855f).